# Riemann sum estimation

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

If given $ \int\limits_a^b f \left( x \right) \mathrm{d}x $ 
 
and the function contains both intervals of concavity up and concavity down within the limits of integration $[a,b]$, and given that:

on an interval of concavity down $[r,s]$ 
$ Trapezoid(n) <  \int\limits_r^s f \left( x \right) \mathrm{d}x < Midpoint(n) $, 
on an interval of concavity up $[p,q]$ 
$ Midpoint(n) <  \int\limits_p^q f \left( x \right) \mathrm{d}x < Trapezoid(n) $, 
could we generalize that:

$ Midpoint(n) <\int\limits_a^b f \left( x \right) \mathrm{d}x < Trapezoid(n) $ or 
 $ Trapezoid(n) < \int\limits_a^b f \left( x \right) \mathrm{d}x<  Midpoint(n) $ 
?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by proper assumptions. Midpoint and trapezoid Riemann sums with n rectangles or trapezoids.

Comment: I'm asking if we know that the actual value of an integral *always* lies between a midpoint or trapezoid Riemann sum even when the function contains intervals of concavity up and concavity down over the interval of  the limits of integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly false that the integral must lie between the midpoint and trapezoid approximations for every $n$. For example, take the function $\cos x$ on $[0,4\pi]$ with $n=1$: the two approximations are both $4\pi$, but the integral equals $0$. (If you don't like $n=1$, take $\cos mx$ for any positive integer $m$ and $n=m$ - same result.)